# solus menu at bottom of screen

Tags: menu, solus

I updated my Solus installation to 1.1 and now it has the menu at the top. How do I move that to the bottom?

I found a forum entry but the contribution that should contain the answer says:

> It's very simple,
>   just open the budgie-panel and in the right upper corner you will see the well known icon for settings.
>   Just push it and the world will go open.

That is just hocus-pocus to me (and I rather not have chasm open up near my home).

Comment: Don't answer your question _in_ the question, add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: As I indicated what I quoted is is hocus-pocus to me, not a answer. I still don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only simple if you know what you need to do and that forum post doesn't help much if you don't.

- In the top right of the menu click the Bell icon, the audio level icon **or** the switch off icon (Red 1) [image]
- A menu should show with two TABs (Applets, Notifications)
- Determine that there are **two** cogwheels/gears in the area that just openened. The one at the bottom is the general settings, which you don't want. Click the cogwheel next to the Notifications TAB (near top right of the screen) (Red 2)
- This opens the Budgie Settings, click on the Panel TAB at the top
- The second row should say Position  Top, change that to Position Bottom

The world did not open near my place, YMMV.